# Can't make a Google Apps Script publish for anonymous users

Tags: google-apps-script

I've built a Google Apps Script and when I try to publish it won't show an option to allow anonymous users. There are only two options: "Only myself" and "Anyone within mydomain.com"

We're using Google Apps for Business (or Work is it now?).

How do I make the other options available?

Answer (score 3):

Sharing outside your Google Apps Domain may be disabled in Admin Console.

In your [Google Apps Admin Console](https://admin.google.com), go to *Google Apps* section, then *Drive*, click *Sharing Settings* and check that **"Users can share files outside this organization"** option is selected. Also select appropriate checkboxes below that option as necessary.

If your organization policies prevent sharing outside your domain, you can create and deploy your webapp from your personal gmail account instead.