# Web app doesn't deploy: Sorry, unable to open the file at present

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a AppsScript in my Google Sheet that I want to deploy as a WebApp (something I've done many times before).
I have deployed it as public (Anyone, even anonymous), and the link comes up with:
"Sorry, unable to open the file at present.
Please check the address and try again."

This also happens when I click "Test web app for your latest code"

The script works perfectly from within the spreadsheet, and my deployment code is:

```
    function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Weekly.html')
      .evaluate();
}

function onOpen() {
  var Menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Survey');
      Menu.addItem('Run Survey', 'doSurvey')
        .addToUi();
}

function doSurvey() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Weekly.html')
      .evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, ' ');
}
```

Any hints?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been resolved in this [github forum](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/issues/163): Can't submit the form, Receiving "Sorry, unable to open the file at present."

And the suggested solution is to :

```
just remove the user part of the URL should work too, e.g. for the OP:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyO4vXIPrq4smOSFpUzyQSuOxvJE9YWqlND6GfyZ3Y2lR-pPMk/exec

we should add this to the tutorial, I suppose. also relevant for some gsuite users:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153872/cant-make-a-google-apps-script-publish-for-anonymous-users
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has not been fixed and still is going on. This happens when you login to multiple google account. Either logout of all, or open your link in a private tab.