# gspread.exceptions.RequestError 404

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gspread

When read/write from the google sheets, have this error:

```
gspread.exceptions.RequestError: (404, '404: b\'<!DOCTYPE html>
...
Sorry, unable to open the file at present.</p><p> Please check the address and try again.</p>
```

The code has been working for many years but it suddenly gets this error without any changes being made. The following is the code. I've created a new credential json file but it also does not work.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("credentialfile.json", SCOPES)
connection = gspread.authorize(credentials)
worksheet = connection.open(self.sheet).worksheet(tab)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be the solution to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672900/web-app-doesnt-deploy-sorry-unable-to-open-the-file-at-present

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/121088347

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. It was because of a change on Google's side to require v4 of the sheets API. (The link that @MattKing pointed me to the answer)

Solution that worked for me: `pip install -U gspread`. I was on 0.6.2, it upgraded to 4.0.1 and everything worked on the first try.