# Dev branch of Apps Script project is sometimes not found

Tags: google-apps-script

When I try to access the dev branch of my Apps Script web app, it will work on some days, but other days will display this error:
[image: Sorry, unable to open tthe file at present. Please check the address and try again.]

My project uses one library which I have ownership of and full access to. It has been deployed multiple times, and the published deployments work fine.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058969/how-to-fix-sorry-unable-to-open-the-file-at-present-error-when-accessing-dev

Comment: My bad!! I tried my best to look for pre-existing questions about this but couldn't find them.

Comment: @Lewis I always search too but ... funnily your question was not closed. Have a look here if it is realated to your issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207485323

Comment: @Lewis - do not worry, duplicate suggestions are for "maintenance" of the knowledge base. If we thought this as a 100% duplicate, it would have been closed immediately. But seems like the issue is either similar or the same indeed - unfortunately, hard to verify. Are you saying everything is the same? Same browser, same logged in user(s), same URL, same everything on different days ends up in 404? Please, provide information about your setup in the way Radek did

Comment: @Lewis if you think your and my issues are similar please comment on the Google issuetracker

Comment: I'm starting to suspect clasp is part of the issue. My dev deployment was working fine until I pushed new code from vs code via clasp and now I'm getting the 'Sorry, unable to open file at present' error again.